# Creating an Array of values from an Array of Dictionaries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

The question sounds weird but I'm getting an array of dictionaries as parsed result.

Something like this:

```
parsed content: (
        {
        "name" = "John";
        "lastname" = "Doe";
        "foo" = "bar";
    }
```

What would be the suggestion for best way to create an array of values??

Comment: Do you already have a way to parse the results (and you just need help building an array/dictionary), or are you looking for a solution that includes parsing code?

Comment: I just need the way to create the array of values. The problem is that I have dictionaries in an array.

Comment: I think I should be more clear, I want to create array of keys and objects.

Comment: Can you be more specific? You want an array containing the keys and a second array containing the objects, or you want an Objective-C dictionary pairing the key-values?

Comment: Yes, exactly two arrays of objects and keys, sorry for being complicated. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
- (void)flattenDictionary:(NSDictionary *)d intoKeys:(NSMutableArray *)keys andValues:(NSMutableArray *)values {

    for (id key in [d allKeys]) {
        [keys addObject:key];
        [values addObject:[d valueForKey:key]];
    }
}

- (void)flattenDictionaries:(NSArray *)arrayOfDictionaries {

    NSMutableArray *keys = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSDictionary *d in arrayOfDictionaries) {
        [self flattenDictionary intoKeys:keys andValues:values];
    }

    NSLog(@"now we have these values %@", values);
    NSLog(@"corresponding to these keys %@", keys);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the values with:

```
NSArray *values = dictionary.allValues;
```

Or, loop through it:

```
[dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@ = %@", key, object);
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

To do that loop through them and create an array.